# How to import CSS Framework within lit-element css style property?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, semantic-ui, lit-element

I am currently using `lit-element` web components for a project. The CSS framework I am using is `semantic-ui`. I have seperated my css styles into their own files in order to be shared accross components. I am currently trying to share`semantic-css` across my whole web components. Since the shadow `dom` encapsulate css styles, selectors do not cross the shadow boundary. This is my current implementation to have a global common styles across my web components. For

app-css.js

```
import { css } from "lit-element";

export default css` SEMANTIC CSS HERE`
```

app.js

```
import globalSemanticCSS from "../styles/css-utils/app-css";
class App extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return [
      globalSemanticCSS, //does not work
      testCss,
      css`
        h1 {
          color: blue;
        }
      `,
    ];
  }
```

I do not understand why `cssText` property is `undefined` [As you can see in the img the property is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4uJH.png)

The lit-element documentation states and shows you can do this.

```
An array of tagged template literals.

static get styles() {
  return [ css`...`, css`...`];
}
```

I am not sure if my `globalSemanticCSS` is to large for the css property to add? If anyone has any suggestion in how I can use a CSS Framework like semantic to be globaly shared across the app I will gladly take the help. Thanks~

Comment: `An array of tagged template literals.` - globalSemanticCSS and testCss seems strings.

Comment: can you explain more? Is that what I am doing?

Comment: @connexo I am I not adding those variables as string literals.

Comment: Do you have a demo or something? Without seeing the actual contents of globalSemanticCSS it's hard to identify the actual problem

Answer (score 2):

Modern method: Only work with chromium based browser.
Read more [Using CSS module scripts](https://web.dev/css-module-scripts/)

```
import styles from './my-styles.css' assert { type: 'css' }; 
class MyEl extends LitElement { 
  static styles = [styles];
}
```

Other solution:
By using vite build tools:

```
import style from "./style.css?inline";
class MyEl extends LitElement { 
  static styles = unsafeCSS(style);
}
```

Other hack: Disable shadow Root 
Add this inside your class

```
createRenderRoot() {
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Late, but very well-informed answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *'default'* export.
You must use a const variable.

Change your code by:

```
import { css } from 'lit-element';

export const globalSemanticCSS = css` SEMANTIC CSS HERE`;
```